# How to run curl in xampp

Tags: curl, xampp, balanced-payments

I'm using xampp, and it looks like curl is installed and enabled by default. phpinfo() says:

```
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.24.0
```

This line is uncommented in php.ini:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

But when I try to run curl, it says:

```
c:\xampp\php>curl
'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable cURL
Check these locations
c:\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini
c:\xampp\php\php.ini

Look for 
;extension=php_curl.dll
remove the ;

restart apache.

It looks like you are trying to use cURL via command line on windows as if it was unix.
At the stage you are at you can use it via a php script.